# Incoming call center software

Tags: networking, voip, voice-recording

I am looking for software which could connect my computer with primary rate interface (PRI) lines or landline phone.

The callers will call my number and they should listen the interactive voice response (IVR). They have to dial an extension. According to IVR or extension dialed by the caller, the call should be routed (land) to any Mobile Phone. I need to record the calls too.

The software may run on Windows 8.1 and above or Linux distribution Ubuntu;
I have no idea of price.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Saket – looks OK to me now. What's not exactly clear to me is how the landline is connected to your computer (you might need additional hardware here; keyword: [Asterisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk_%28PBX%29)) – but it's not my area of expertise to tell. So all I can do now is to wish you good luck with matching recommendations!

Comment: Yes ! It will need some hardware.

Comment: While *explicitly asking* for hardware is off-topic here, if your software-request turns out to need some such component answers can of course mention that :) So fingers crossed, and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I've been working with Voiptimecloud [Inbound call centre software](https://voiptimecloud.com/call-center/inbound-call-center-software) for some time,they specialize in developing inbound, outbound and blended software. By the way, inbound software has lots of benefits and valuable points:

- Improved Reporting Features
- Enhanced Productivity And Efficiency
- Enhanced Data Access
- Increased Communication And Responsibility

There is also free trial on their website.